Create additional rows based on Column value
I want to expand my data frame based on numeric values in a column (index_end). My df looks like this:



item
index_end




A
3


B
4


C
1



I want this to expand to create rows for A from 1 to 3 and rows for B from 1 to 4 and create partitioned index.



item
index_end
index




A
3
1


A
3
2


A
3
3


B
4
1


B
4
2


B
4
3


B
4
4


C
1
1



Looking for a solution in Python/pandas. Thanks!

Combine index.repeat, loc, and groupby.cumcount:
out = (df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['index_end'])]
         .assign(index=lambda x: x.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1))
      )

Output:
  item  index_end  index
0    A          3      1
0    A          3      2
0    A          3      3
1    B          4      1
1    B          4      2
1    B          4      3
1    B          4      4
2    C          1      1

Or using pure numpy with np.repeat and np.cumsum:
out = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df, df['index_end'], axis=0), columns=df.columns)
a = df['index_end'].to_numpy()
out['index'] = (np.repeat(np.cumsum(a[::-1]), a[::-1])-np.arange(len(out)))[::-1]

Output:
  item index_end  index
0    A         3      1
1    A         3      2
2    A         3      3
3    B         4      1
4    B         4      2
5    B         4      3
6    B         4      4
7    C         1      1


import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'item': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'index_end': ['3', '4', '1']})
duplicate_rows = lambda value,iterate: sum([[str(v)]*int(i) for v,i in zip(value,iterate)],[])
custom_index = lambda old_index: sum([list(range(1,int(i)+1)) for i in old_index],[])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'item': duplicate_rows(df.item,df.index_end), 'index_end': duplicate_rows(df.index_end,df.index_end), "index": custom_index(df.index_end)})

Output:



item
index_end
index




A
3
1


A
3
2


A
3
3


B
4
1


B
4
2


B
4
3


B
4
4


C
1
1



UPD: thank you @mozway for the advise, bellow I've replace "sum" with "functools" and "operator".
import pandas as pd
import functools
import operator

df = pd.DataFrame({'item': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'index_end': ['3', '4', '1']})
duplicate_rows = lambda value,iterate: functools.reduce(operator.iconcat,[[str(v)]*int(i) for v,i in zip(value,iterate)],[])
custom_index = lambda old_index: functools.reduce(operator.iconcat,[list(range(1,int(i)+1)) for i in old_index],[])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'item': duplicate_rows(df.item,df.index_end), 'index_end': duplicate_rows(df.index_end,df.index_end), "index": custom_index(df.index_end)})


You should not use sum to merge lists, this has a quadratic behavior. Go with itertools.chain that is linear, or a good old nested list comprehension ;)

Sure, let me try it.

See How do I make a flat list out of a list of lists?

Yes, you are absolute right, "sum" is a very inefficient way because of the quadratic aspect.
The itertools is better oprtion.
res = list(itertools.chain(*[[str(v)]*int(i) for v,i in zip(df.item,df.index_end)]))

Alternatively:
df = (df.assign(index = df['index_end'].map(lambda x: range(1,x+1) if x >1 else x))
        .explode('index', ignore_index = True))

which gives:
  item  index_end index
0   A           3     1
1   A           3     2
2   A           3     3
3   B           4     1
4   B           4     2
5   B           4     3
6   B           4     4
7   C           1     1


First create a column with a list which is the range of the index_end column, so it is a list like this: range(1 , index_end[i] + 1) for the row i
to solve this problem you should perform the code below:
df['index'] = df['index_end'].apply(lambda num: list(range(1, num + 1)))

now if you check your index column you see some lists. There is way to explode this lists, and it is also called df.explode, it takes each list in the index column and then creates new rows for each element of that list which at then end solves your problem. just use the code below:
expanded_df = df.explode('index').reset_index(drop=True)

note that the .reset_index(drop=True) is just to update the real index of the dataframe you have.

import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'item': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
                   'index_end': [3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1]})


df['index'] = df.groupby('item').cumcount() + 1

print(df)
"""
 item  index_end  index
0    A          3      1
1    A          3      2
2    A          3      3
3    B          4      1
4    B          4      2
5    B          4      3
6    B          4      4
7    C          1      1
"""

